# How to migrate away from ASP.NET Core Identity?

Tags: asp.net-core

We are maximally dissatisfied with ASP.NET Core Identity, especially with the Razor Pages, all the stores and managers. The validations are the very worst. You can hardly implement everyday scenarios. And if you then ask on GitHub, you get the answer that this was not a planned scenario. And why the heck is it so tightly integrated with Entity Framework.
Please do not discuss this. We just want to move away from ASP.NET Core Identity. As soon as possible.

So, how to offboard ASP.NET Core Identity? Which ways to go, what to consider?

We still want to stay with ASP.NET Core and also use 2-factor authentication. However, implementing password check alone with the same mechanisms is unknown. There is nothing documented at Microsoft.

Thank you very much.

Comment: What exactly are you asking? How to re-implement parts of ASP.NET Core identity without using it?

Comment: Hi @PeterLiguda, if you don't want to use Asp.net core Identity, when create the application using the template, no select the "Individual Accounts" authentication type. If you have selected it, you can remove the Identity Areas and the identity related service in the program.cs or Statup.cs file. Then, you can refer to the [official Multi-factor authentication documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/mfa?view=aspnetcore-6.0), when validate the user, you can access the database via DBContext, instead of usermanager or signmanager.

Comment: @davidfowl oh wow, thanks for your reply. Yes, we right now have a user base created via ASP.NET Core Identity.  We want to move away from ASP.NET Core Identity, but we still want to implement a secure login with ASP.NET, but now we have to do it ourselves. We don't want to change the passwords and we also want to keep 2 factor authentication with OTP. We need an off boarding guide for ASP.NET Core Identity. So yes, it's about re-implementing the password stuff and the login stuff (login/2fa with via ASP.NET Core SignIn())